# Puppet ruby template with ip validation - skip failed values not error and stop

Tags: ruby, validation, templates, ip, puppet

I have the following code in a Puppet (ruby) .erb template with a validate function on each value that is iterated over from an array.  I want it to continue with next values and preferably issue a warning, or silently continue.  The code below errors and stops if an entry fails validation.

For example if the array is $nameservers = ['1.1.1.1','/some.domain/2.2.2.2'] I want it to only process the 1.1.1.1 entry.

This is actually so I can use the same input array for either /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/dnsmask.conf as determined by other logic in my manifest that gets processed by one of 2 templates (no, I'm not crazy)  :).

I know that validation can be done in the manifest or on top scope variables, however I have a need to do this in the template.

```
search <%= scope.lookupvar('dns_search') %>
<% scope.lookupvar('nameservers').each do |server| -%>
<% if scope.function_validate_ip_address([server]) -%>
nameserver <%= server -%>

<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the following code.  The only thing I can't get to add is a trailing newline after the LAST entry only.  Any comments on how this block could be improved appreciated.

```
search <%= scope.lookupvar('dns_search') %>    
<% scope.lookupvar('nameservers').each do |server| -%>    
<% begin -%>    
<% if scope.function_validate_ip_address([server]) %>    
nameserver <%= server -%>    
<% end -%>    
<% rescue => e -%>    
<% scope.call_function('warning',[e]) -%>    
<% next %>    
<% end -%>    
<% end -%>
```